# Can I say "he shuffled to bed"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I want to describe someone who is tired and is going to bed dragging his feet on the ground. A google search of "shuffled to bed" or "shuffled to his bed" gave me very few hits (at first I got thousands of them, but when I scrolled down the page to see them all they were reduced to only a few)
Are there more common verbs or expressions that I can use to write this action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, **shuffled** does work—but it takes the form [**shuffled off**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shuffle%20off):

> transitive verb
>   to get rid of : push away : SHIRK
>   when we have shuffled off this mortal coil —Shakespeare
>   shuffle off the heavy burden of our guilt —Richard Chase
>  
>   teachers cannot … shuffle off their responsibility —C. I. Glicksberg
>
> intransitive verb
>   to be on one's way : mosey along
>       let him shuffle off to the wilderness —J. B. Priestley

In your case:

> He shuffled off to bed.